# Rectify 250A using multiple bridge rectifier

Tags: three-phase, bridge-rectifier

Need to rectify 3 phase 120V AC 250A using 3 Phase 200A bridge rectifier.
Details:
Input Voltage: 120V AC 3 Phase
Input Current: 250A

Problem: Only 3 Phase 200A bridge rectifier is available. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Three of these sort of diode pairs should do it SKKD 260/16

[image]

Forced air heatsinking is a must, three modules with an average rectified current of 250A is about 500 Watts of power loss according to semikrons datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

First, is your load 250A or is that the max for the mains circuit?  Your rectifier only has to meet the amperage of the load.

If you really need 250A, then you can use individual diodes to make the bridge or you can use 2 single phase bridge rectifiers (really just 1/2 of the second single phase bridge).

Or, you can look some more and find one like this...
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ixys/MDMA900U1600PTEH/11304990

Comment: I'd like to maximize my source which is 250A or at least make sure I don't overload the rectifier.  Thanks.